# Json parsing error: Value jsonStr of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

When I run the following code It does not display data.It shows the following error message:

```
2019-11-16 14:40:19.149 17562-17585/com.example.jsonparsing E/MainActivity: Response from url: <html>

    <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
    </html>

2019-11-16 14:40:19.149 17562-17585/com.example.jsonparsing E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: Value jsonStr of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-11-16 14:40:19.164 17562-17589/com.example.jsonparsing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-11-16 14:40:19.172 17562-17589/com.example.jsonparsing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
```

`MainActivity`:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        new getContacts().execute();

    }

    class getContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JSON Data is" +
                    " downloading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... Void) {

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonStr");

                    List<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacts");

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String office = phone.getString("office");

                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);
                        contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }

                    return contactList;

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsing error: "
                                    + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                adapter.add(result);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`HttpHandler`:

```
class HttpHandler {
    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    HttpHandler() {
    }

    String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl){

        String response = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);

        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"MalformException: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (ProtocolException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;

    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is){
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            is.close();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I would guess that they moved to HTTPS. Try changing your URL: `https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/`.

Comment: Yep: https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work!

Comment: Oh, I see it. You have another error, too. `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonStr");` – No quotes around `jsonStr`. You want the variable there, not a `String`.

Comment: @Mike M I removed double quotes but showing same error message!

Comment: I just ran your code with the two changes I noted, and a generic `ListView`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUFKI.jpg.

Comment: @Mike M But I couldn't run..Please help me

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help without knowing what the current, exact error is. If you made the changes I suggested correctly, it's not either of the ones you posted here in the question and title.

Comment: @Mike M. My current problem is:MainActivity: Json parsing error: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @Mike M. also showing this error messsge:  2019-11-16 19:07:13.812 21596-21613/com.example.jsonparsing E/MainActivity: Response from url: <html>
    <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: I am new to android. So please help me

Comment: @Mike M. Its a built in url. I just used this url for learning. Really I don't know how would I change this url. I followed the following link code : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm for learning. And I used that url  that had give on that code as I am newbie in android and json.

Comment: Look at your code. The second thing in the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method: `String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";`. Change it to `https`.

Comment: @Mike M. It's working. Thank you so very much.